# info.plist contains #include "../unix/buildinfo.h" which is causing issue

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, xcode7, info.plist

My library(C/C++) was working perfectly fine on MacOSX 10.10 I was using base SDK 10.8. In my library there was a dependency on "Appletalk" framework. when I tried to build it on MacOSX 10.11 using Base SDK 10.11 it started throwing error "Appletalk framework not found" , I looked for framework in SDK and it is not present there so i removed Appletalk framework from dependency list. Now it has started giving some strange error I don't know how to resolve it.

```
#include "../unix/buildinfo.h"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>English</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>Linguistic</string>
<key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
<string> Linguistic Library  LILO_MAJOR_MINOR_MICRO_VERSION</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.linguistic.LinguisticManager</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>VERSION</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>FMWK</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>LILO_MAJOR_MINOR_MICRO_VERSION</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>RELEASECL</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As you can see now updated plist contains header file entry that I guess should not be there as **it is throwing error "../unix/buildinfo.h" not found.**

Comment: ay help'll be appreaciated

Comment: alternative framework for appletalk will also work I guess, but I am unable to find one. thanks